# Many UIButton in .xib with different tags

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have 17 button in my xib. And I have set them tag values 1 to 17.

Can somebody can tell me, how to connect all 17 buttons with a single variable name in .h and get a particular button in .m with it's tag value.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this, and I know that if you select all your buttons in storyboards, and control drag them to the appropriate controller in an assistant editor you can create a collection of outlets representing all the buttons. The resulting code was:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *buttons;
```

Answer (score 1):

no its not possible as per my experience. IBOutlet i.e. Interface Builder Outlet always refers to a single connection between an interface component (like button) and a variable in interface (like IBOutlet UIButton *myButton). This one-to-one relation.

Comment: Is it possible in case of labels? Not in UiButton?

Comment: i think you didn't my point. Please read it again. It covers each and evry compeonent of interface builder.

Answer (score 1):

There needs to be an `IBOutlet` per button, so you'll need to create all 17 of them. Connect buttons to outlets individually, and then you will be able to put them into an array inside your initializer if you need them in an array.

You can save on the `IBAction` methods, though: make one method like this

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
}
```

You can connect this method to all buttons, and look at the tag of the `(id)sender` to decide which button called your action.

Comment: my bad..does it mean i have to create 17 IBOutlet variables in xib!!

Comment: @turtle Yes, you will need to create 17 IBOutlet variables, but you do not have to use them beyond your designated `init` method, where you could group them all into an array or an `NSArray`.

Comment: yea, done that..thanks..:) ..but the code has become redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You can't give a one reference to 17 button but you can assign one method to 17 buttons like @dasblinkenlight said

You have to just set the `IBAction` method to all button clicked event
and using tag value you can access the button which you want

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {

     int j = [sender tag];
     NSLog(@"Clicked Button %i", j);

}
```

Comment: but, i don't want to touch the button, just want to set its selected property to YES or NO. Thanks anyways..